# Calculating Fourier magnitude spectrum for Local Binary Pattern histogram

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, fourier-analysis

I have the follwoing discrete Fourier transform function defined in my book (Computer Vision using Local Binary Patterns, Pietikainen et. al, 2011):

$$H(n, u ) = \sum_{r=0}^{P-1}c_{nr} \exp(\frac{-iur2\pi}{P}),$$

where $u\in\{0, 1, ..., P/2\}$, $n\in\{1,2, ..., P-1\}$, $P$ is a positive integer, $i$ is the imaginary number and $c_{nr}$ is some positive integer greater or equal to zero.

I need to calculate the Fourier magnitude spectrum:

$$|H(n,u)| = \sqrt{H(n,u)\overline{H(n,u)}}$$

Can someone show me the explicit steps for doing the actual computation of $|H(n,u)| $? I tried to calculate it myself, but I think I made a mistake somewhere, because I couldn't get it to evaluate as a real number...

P.S. If there is more information required I'm happy to supply :) Here you can find my reference [Computer Vision using Local Binary Patterns](http://www.pakyazilim.com/sayfa/image/yz/LBP/Computer_Vision_Using%20Local_Binary%20Patterns.pdf) (page 20). The author is using different terms though than I am on some occasions.

UPDATE:

Might this help at all: [Rotation Invariant Image Description with Local
Binary Pattern Histogram Fourier Features](http://www.ee.oulu.fi/mvg/files/pdf/SCIA2009_lbp_histogram_fourier.pdf) (pages 63-66)

Comment: Plancherel's Therorem states
$$\Vert u \Vert_2 = \Vert \hat u \Vert_2$$
Also, where does you $n$ get used in the definiton of $H(u,n)$?

Comment: +1 Thank you for your help, darm, sorry about that =) I will add $n$ in the formula. Actually I could take the $n$ out completely, it doesn't affect the computation here, it just specifies a certain group of positive integers =)

Comment: using $\overline{\exp(-ix)}=\exp(ix)$ you should arrive somewhere around $$\sqrt{\sum_{r=1}^{P-1} c_{nr}^2}$$...

Comment: +1 Thnx @AlexR I will try to do it myself =) If someone could show at least a bit of details explicitly I can accept the answer =)